Centered-difference left Neumann boundary condition discretization when integrating equation inward
I want to discretize the following nonlinear equation on a domain $[0, R]$:
$\frac{dA}{dr} + F(A) = 0$,
where $F$ is a nonlinear operator, with the left boundary condition at large finite radius $r = R$:
$A|_{r=R} = A_N$ (a known constant) and $\frac{dA}{dr} = 0$. My goal is to integrate the equation from $r = R$ inward, using centered-difference forms for the derivatives. Let $r = r_i$ ($i = 1, 2, ..., N$), $h \equiv r_{i+1}-r_i$ and $A_i \equiv A(r_i)$. After rearranging, this gives
$A_{i-1} = A_{i+1}+2\,h\,F(A_i)\quad\quad\quad(*)$,
and the boundary condition
$A_{N-1} = A_{N+1}\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(**)$.
That's when I start to get confused. Starting at index $i = N$, we have
$A_{N-1} = A_{N+1}+2\,h\,F(A_N)\quad\quad(***)$.
Here, the second term on the right-hand side is known and non zero, and we have $A_{N-1} = A_{N+1}$ from the boundary condition. However, when replacing $(**)$ in $(***)$, this implies that the second term on the right-hand side be zero. What am I doing wrong? And how to estimate $A_{N-1}$ when $A_{N+1}$ is also unknown? I am obviously missing something here.
